# What font is this (from Gunrox)?

Tags: font-identification

I've tried WhatTheFont, Identifont, WhatFontIs and another few services with no luck.  What fonts are these?  (The font is white on transparent, so download to view properly.)

This font is from a game, [Gunrox](http://www.gunrox.com/).  It appears throughout the game and is found in the /texture/fonts/ folder.  Is this a real font, or maybe there's nothing like it, if it was developed solely for the game?  What's similar?

[(Font picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPU3p.png)

[image: Font #1]

Comment: You'll need a better quality sample of the font, but there's an online tool for identifying fonts, and for me it's always worked really well. [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: That would be a bitmap font, most probably created from an existing font specifically for that game. [This post on gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/tool-to-create-a-bitmap-font-from-a-true-type-font) has some tools for converting regular fonts to bitmap fonts for games. Due to the nature of low res bitmap fonts I'm not sure you'll have much like with font identification services.

Comment: Your image is really difficult to see. However, it appears to be a bitmapped version of Helvetica Bold or Arial Bold -- probably the latter, given your other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What font is this? (second font from Gunrox)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69241/what-font-is-this-second-font-from-gunrox)

Comment: @elegant they are two separate fonts, and the rules say one font per question

Answer (score 3):

I've inverted the image and cut it to only the letters. Then I've overlayed it with both Verdana and Arial. At first I thought it was Verdana, but as you can see Arial is actually closer. The fact that it's not Verdana is most noticeable in the uppercase J, Q, M and lowercase y. Arial is much closer, only the uppercase I is different, probably for legibility.

[image: Gunrox font]

[image: Gunrox font large]

Comment: Black is from my image and red is your overlay?  I guess the N is just a positioning difference.

Comment: I can't get Arial Text to match - what font size and format are you using?

Comment: Yes, red is my overlay. I didn't bother too much with positioning, since there were 52 letters to do and I just wanted to show Arial is closer than Verdana. I just used Arial Bold in Photoshop. I'm on a Windows10 machine if that's any help.